# Using gitlab interface

Tags: gitlab

I am in a process of learning gitlab and have created some test projects.

But I just cannot figure out how to delete these projects. I do not see any "Dangerous Settings " options on my page/project as some forums suggest.
(Please see attached picture of my gitlab page to see what I see)

Please note : when I click on my projects I get "404 Page not found" but the activity log shows that I have pushed files.

[image: Gitlab page screen shot]

[image: After clicking on the project I get Error 404]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I depends on the version of GitLab you are using.
[Issue 9890](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/9890) mentions:

> When you want to remove a project in its settings (`/<owner>/<project>/edit`) and confirm the pop-up (where you have to enter the project's name), the project is deleted..
>
> But you're not redirected to a different site automatically. Since the project is gone, the current site `/<owner>/<project>/edit` does not exist anymore so you're getting a 404.

This was fixed in 8.2.3 ([commit 2497d3d](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/2497d3d550dc0d4e095c8c3fe75d4452fb163252))

Answer (score 0):

You can delete those projects from admin area.

- Login with the admin account
- Go to `Admin area` (the wrench icon on the top right corner)
- Click on `Projects` on the left side bar

There is a list of your projects, then just delete what you want.

(I am using GitLab 8.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

I realized I wasn't enrolled as admin . That is why I wasn't seeing the gear tool to modify my projects.

Thank you Van and Issue 9890 for your response.